# Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: asp.net-mvc, node.js

We are using Node Js for our front end and we are accessing Dot.Net Web API services from backend, for Login process using Owin it is generating an error Cross Origin

The error is as follows,

Token - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

and following are the response headers we are getting and request headers we sent to call the service, scr-shot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJD17.png)

Answer (score 0):

Install CORS package Nuget in your application

> *Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors*

Then in your WebApiConfig class, put:

```
config.EnableCors();
```

in Register static function.

Then, in your requested controller class, put this annotation :

```
[EnableCors(origins: "\*", headers: "\*", methods: "*")]
```

Should do the trick. You have further information right here :

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api